# How to assign and access the id of the td of the table in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm inserting the row dynamically. How can I assign the id to each td so I can access it and update it after time. I'm sticking in it

```
                       $(document).ready(function(){
            var rowNumber = 0;
            var myData=new Array(6);
            myData[0]="txt1";
            myData[1]="txt2";
            myData[2]="txt3";
            myData[3]="txt4";
            myData[4]="txt5";
            myData[5]="txt6";
            $('#display').click(function(){
                //Get the user input
                for(i=0; i<6; i++)
                {
                if(document.getElementById(myData[i]).value !=0)
                {
                var nameInput = document.getElementById(myData[i]).name;

                var Quan = document.getElementById(myData[i]).value;
                //Create a new row with an ID
                var newRow = $('<tr />').attr('id', 'row' + rowNumber);
                //Add some HTML to the row



                newRow.html('<td>' + nameInput + '</td><td>' + Quan + '</td>');

                //Append the new row to the body of the #myTable table
                $('#myTable tbody').append(newRow);

                //Iterate row number
                rowNumber++;

                }
                }
            });
        });
```

I'm inserting the row dynamically. How can I assign the id to each td so I can access it and update it after time. I'm sticking in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to.  You can use jQuery's `nth()` selector.

For example:

```
$('td:nth(2)').html()
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Uz4Ze/

Alternatively, I would suggest assigning each `<td>` a class, instead of an `id`. This will give you the added benefit of being able to style each column differently.

Answer (score 0):

***YOU DON'T NEED IT***

```
var td = $('#myTable tr:eq(2) td:eq(1)'); // 3 row 2 col
```

*SEE [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vrvMQ/)*

***BUT IF YOU WANT***

Write something like:

```
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  ...
  newRow.append('<td id="' + ('td_' + rowNumber + '_1') + '">' + nameInput + '</td>');
  newRow.append('<td id="' + ('td_' + rowNumber + '_2') + '">' + nameInput + '</td>');
  ...
}
```

Then to access:

```
$('#2_1').css('background', '#ccc'); // make grey background in 2 row 1 col
```